# Check if bulk is empty in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to check if Mongodb bulk has some operations to do before calling .execute() on it? 
I am pretty sure I don't send any empty objects to insert but keep getting this error on one document

```
Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk
```

Here is some code:

```
bulk.find({"AcctSessionId":insert['AcctSessionId']}).upsert().update({$set:insert});
```

and insert object looks like this

```
{ AcctStatusTypeU: '3',
  AcctSessionId: '1183628512-105130252',
  h323setuptimeU: '<sip:27117929995@41.66.146.252>',
  h323connecttimeU: Sun Mar 08 2015 19:30:37 GMT+0100 (CET),
  AcmeSessionEgressRealmU: '620',
  AcmeSessionIngressRealmU: 'CORE_PSX' 
}
```

I see my objects inserted but still get this error. By the way this is a Nodejs driver I am talking about and I am using UNorderedBulkOp to insert documents.

Comment: I guess there is no method to do this check...

Answer (score 16):

I run into the same problem. Check bulk.length

```
if (bulk.length > 0) {
    // run bulk operations
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is correct for the node driver, but it's wrong for the mongo shell, at least.

Comment: It is correct for the mongo driver.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/UnorderedBulkOperation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check wether an bulk operation has operations to execute:

```
bulk
```

returns something like this

```
{ "nInsertOps" : 0, "nUpdateOps" : 1, "nRemoveOps" : 0, "nBatches" : 1 }
```

The reason why your bulk operation actually is empty is because your `h323connecttimeU`holds an illegal value  – you need to quote the date string.

Furthermore, you are using the bulk operation in a wrong way. It should be

```
bulk.find({"AcctSessionId":insert['AcctSessionId']}).upsert().updateOne(insert);
```

Comment: nope, the date is fine I just copied it but it is instantiated like new Date("date string"), not sure about the upsert part since it works just fine like this, will test. How do you use "bulk" in code. My guess is that you use it like you wrote in console right?

Comment: @vodich Correct, since that is MongoDBs [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca). And you don't need to set your `insert` document, you only need to set individual fields.